# Prove that odd polynomials have at least one root.

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials, roots

Intuitively this is easy for me to understand, but I don't know how to start the proof. Can someone help me?

> Prove that any polynomial of the form $x^n+\sum_{i<n}a_{i}x_{i}$, with $a_{i}\in \mathbb{R}$ and $n$ *odd*, has at least one real root.

Comment: Hint: polynomials are continuous functions, and the limits of an odd degree polynomial at $\pm \infty$ are $\cdots$

Comment: What is $x_i$ supposed to be? Is it a typo for $x^i$?

Comment: $\lim_\limits{x\to-\infty} f(x) = -\infty<0, \lim_\limits{x\to\infty} f(x) = \infty>0, f(x)$ is continuous.   Then by the IVT, there exists a $c\in(-\infty,\infty)$ such that $f(c) = 0$

Comment: None of the answers "prove" anything if they don't prove why the end behaviour of such polynomials is the way it is.

Answer (score 4):

Use Intermediate Value Theorem.

Since $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=\infty$, and $\lim_{x\to-\infty}f(x)=-\infty$, in particular there exists $(a,b)$ such that $f(b)>0$ and $f(a)<0$.

By IVT, there exists $c\in (a,b)$ such that $f(c)=0$.

Answer (score 3):

If
$f(x)
= x^n+\sum_{i<n}a_{i}x^{i}
$,
(you wrote $x_i$;
I assume you meant
$x^i$)
then
for large enough $x$,
$f(x) > 0$.

To show this,
write
$f(x)
= x^n(1+\sum_{i<n}a_{i}x^{i-n})
$.
We want to choose $x$ large enough
so that
$\sum_{i<n}|a_{i}|x^{i-n}
< 1$.
This will be true if
$|a_{i}|x^{i-n}
< \frac1n
$
or
$x^{n-i} > n|a_{i}|
$
or
$x > (n|a_{i}|)^{1/(n-i)}
$.

Therefore,
if
$x > \max_{i<n} (n|a_{i}|)^{1/(n-i)}
$,
$f(x) > 0$.

Note:
There are other, better bounds
that can be worked out.
This is an easy one.

This is true whether
$n$ is even or odd.

If $n$ is odd,
then
$x^n < 0$ for $x < 0$.
Therefore,
if $x < - \max_{i<n} (n|a_{i}|)^{1/(n-i)}$,
then,
as before,
$\sum_{i<n}|a_{i}||x|^{i-n}
< 1$
so that
$|\sum_{i<n}a_{i}x^{i-n}|
\le \sum_{i<n}|a_{i}x^{i-n}|
< 1$
so that
$1+\sum_{i<n}a_{i}x^{i-n}
> 0$.

Therefore,
if $x < - \max_{i<n} (n|a_{i}|)^{1/(n-i)}$,
then
$f(x)
= x^n(1+\sum_{i<n}a_{i}x^{i-n})
< 0
$.

Since $f(x) > 0$
for all large enough $x$
and
$f(x) < 0$
for all negatively large $x$
(with
$|x| > \max_{i<n} (n|a_{i}|)^{1/(n-i)}$
working in both directions),
since $f(x)$ is continuous,
there has to be an $x_0$
such that
$f(x_0) = 0$.

Comment: The root bound is not that bad. As so many other things, it has "Cauchy" in its name. It is just a little inconvenient to compute by hand.

Comment: Thanks for that historical note. As in almost all my answers, I worked this out as I went along. When I saw that I had to make a sum of n terms less than one, my first impulse was to make each term less than 1/n. As for computing the bound by hand, a slide rule will do it nicely.